# problems about cofinality

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to prove the following:

1. $cf(\omega)=\omega$.
2. $cf(\alpha)<\omega$ iff $\alpha$ is successor ordinal.

For 1. define a cofinal map  follows $f\colon \omega\to\omega$ by $f(n)=n+1$. It is clearly unbounded. To argue it is the smallest. Let $m<\omega$ and consider cofinal map from $m\to\omega$ but in this case we will have $$\omega=\bigcup\{f(n)+1\colon n\in m\}$$ It means $\omega$ is finite which is a contradiction since $\omega$ is countable ordinal.

For 2. One direction is obvious. So, assume $cf(\alpha)<\omega$ and we want to show $\alpha$ is successor. $cf(\alpha)=m$ for some $m\in\omega$. So there exists a cofinal map $f\colon m\to\alpha$. As in the previous proof $$\alpha=\bigcup\{f(n)+1\colon n\in m\}$$ So finite union of successor ordinals is successor ordinals (NOT sure).

Please tell me if what I did is correct or not. Also,

Comment: If $\alpha, \beta$ are any two ordinals, then $\alpha \cup \beta = \max \{\alpha, \beta\}$.  The result then follows for finite unions by induction on the number of ordinals in the union.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you. I am not sure why you mentioned to this result here. If this finite union of successors ordinals numbers is ordinal

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo, Could  you please check mt argument

Comment: I mention this result because it establishes that a finite union of successor ordinals is a successor ordinal, which you expressed uncertainty about.  In fact, a finite union of ordinals is simply the largest element of the set.